# "New contributor indicator" misunderstanding

Tags: phrase-meaning, disambiguation

I have just seen a link to a Meta question: [*Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/350184)

For a second I understood the "new contributor indicator" part as "there is a contributor indicator, and that indicator is new". But then I realized that the post is about an indicator that tells if a given post is from a "new contributor".

So my question is: can the title of the post be understood in English as I understood it in the first place? If so, how can the sentence be reworded to avoid the misunderstanding?

Comment: It could, in theory. To solve, hyphenate. E.g. "man-eating fish" *vs* "man eating fish".

Answer (score 2):

The "New Contributor" expression could have been wrapped in `" "`, because "New Contributor" is the actual name that references that particular Indicator.

This way, the phrase would mean

```
we have a new Indicator and it's the "New Contributor" Indicator.
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it's the mischief of initial capitals format used for the title. In proper running text, it would be:

> Come take a look at our New Contributor indicator!

Note that "indicator" has no initial capital(s) but "New Contributor" has.

"New Contributor" is the proper noun and indicator a common noun.

*meta*: I'm not suggesting how it could have been phrased to avoid the ambiguity because rephrasing is not a valid answer.

Comment: -1 please support your answer with reliable reference.

Comment: @user070221 Save your down votes, buddy. Thanks, though.

Comment: the same to you :) have a nice day.